# how to count the elements of different users in sql

Tags: php, sql

I have a query which works correctly however I need to change the user in the where.

```
user1=012345
user2=12121
uer3=878787

    select count(*) as xxx from(
    select a,b,c from tb1 t1 left join tb2 t2 on t1.id=t2.rf 
    where t1.user='012345'
    ) as table
```

how do I dynamically change the where statement so that it evaluates the three users and gives me the results

Answer (score 2):

How about `in`?

```
   where t1.user in (user1, user2, user3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help -

```
select t1.user, count(t1.user) count 
from tb1 t1 
left join tb2 t2 on t1.id = t2.rf 
where t1.user in (012345, 12121, 878787)
group by t1.user
```